# Using FEM for Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: navier-stokes

I'm typically using FEM for solid mechanics problems and when I look into performing fluid-structure interaction, I saw they use FV or SPH method for the fluid domain. I'm not an expert in fluid simulation but considering the Navier-Stokes pdes, I can see that they can well be discretized by FEM. Regardless of the instability that may arise when the Reynolds number is high, what are the benefits of using other discretization methods? Are they able to naturally solve the problem of high Reynolds numbers without using additional stabilization techniques?

Comment: As a starting point, I would take a look at the classic paper by [Bassi and Rebay](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999196955722) in which they showed how to include viscous gradients in DG.

Comment: Many solid mechanics problems satisfy a variational principle, and can be solved by invoking a discreet variational principle. Most fluids problems cannot. Does this account for the differences you are seeing?

Comment: @PhilipRoe that's not the case. NS can well be discretized using FEM.

Comment: @kstn Of course. My concern was that if you had been using variational FEM for solid mechanics you might not be aware of the differences but clearly you are. People doing CFD in various fields choose their methods for many reasons, good and bad. Without knowing more specifically what you have been looking at it is hard to guess what the reasons may be. What is your application area?